# How to iterate through multiple XCUIElements

Tags: ios, xctest, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

Perhaps I misunderstand how the queries and xcuielements work, but I'd like to iterate through the results of a query.

In my app I have the text number sent / number received twice on a screen of my app. I'd like to check that both numbers are the same. For example the following text is on my screen.

```
10/10
0/0
```

I use the following code to find these two static text elements

```
XCUIElement *staticTexts = [self.app.staticTexts elementMatchingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"label contains '/'"]];
```

This fetches me the two static text elements but I have no way to iterate through the two to check the labels. If there were only one element retrieved there wouldn't be a problem unfortunately there are two. If there's a better way to do this please tell me. I'm new to UI Testing.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are calling, `-elementMatchingPredicate:` only returns on element. Note that the method name is singular. Trying to call any method on the returned object will result in an exception being thrown.

I suggest taking a slightly different approach to your tests. Since you are writing the test *you* decide what the first number should be. You can then use that to verify that the second number is the same.

To do so, just set different `-accessibilityIdentifier`s on each of the labels. Then you can assert each one individually.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts[@"Number Input"].value, @"867-5309");
XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts[@"Number Confirm"].value, @"867-5309");
```